# Fetching a MySQL SET column as a list of integer offsets

Tags: sql, mysql, set

I have a table in a MySQL database defined similar to the following:

```
CREATE TABLE doc_types (
    id    INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
    types SET('foo','bar','baz','quux',...) NOT NULL
)
```

I would like to get the value of the `types` column as a comma-separated list of 1-based integer offsets into that list of set values, e.g. `"1,3,4"` for a row whose value is `"foo,baz,quux"`.  (This format is required by another tool in the system I'm working on, and for various practical reasons I'm not able to modify it to accept something different.)  The built-in `EXPORT_SET` function is not entirely dissimilar, but its return value would be in the form `"1,0,1,1,..."`, essentially a 64-element bit set represented in string form.

Is there any good way to `SELECT from doc_types` and get the `types` values back in the offset format I described above, within a single SQL query?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',', 
  IF(types & 1 > 0, 1, NULL), 
  IF(types & 2 > 0, 2, NULL), 
  IF(types & 4 > 0, 3, NULL), 
  /* fill in rest here */
  ) as output 
FROM doc_types;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT MAKE_SET(types+0, '1', '2', '3') as output FROM doc_types;
```